# Can I develop App in Xcode 9.2 for iOS 12?

Tags: ios, xcode, version, capability

I faced the issue that I can only install on Mac Sierra 10.12.6 Xcode 9.2 and it supports the maximum iOS version of 11.x
I want to develop for iOS 12.x and further, can the same code I develop on 9.2 run on devices with iOS 12.x? 
If it’s not available and I’ll buy Mac and install Xcode 10, what are the minimum iOS version I can develop? 
Which Xcode should I use for building app on iOS 12.x and lower? 
Actually I’m doing it with react native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps developed under Xcode 9.2 can run on iOS 12.x.

It's worth to mention that from 1st Mars 2019, Apple Store will refuse app develop with iOS SDK 11 (Xcode 9.x). So if your intention is to publish your app on Apple Store, you must consider to publish it before this deadline, or install Xcode 10.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks pretty much
Is it real to continue working on my project in xcode10 after their refusing?
or one project - one xcode?

Comment: If possible, you should always working on Xcode 10. That will avoid many headache in the future.